# ZenCoding is not working in Visual Studio 2017 community edition

Tags: visual-studio-2017, emmet, web-essentials

I installed web essentials 2017 after downloading it from the Marketplace Link-https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebExtensionPack2017 . Then installed it after closing Visual studio and tried ZenCoding in a razor page. puffff tab doesn't work.

I don't have ReSharper

Answer (score 1):

After going through a lot of blogs, a few suggested the same solution, that we need to follow the installation steps

1. Install Web Essentials
2. Install ZenCoding

Then try ZenCoding, if it doesn't work uninstall both i.e. Web Essentials & ZenCoding and follow set 1 & 2.

This worked for me.

Comment: It seems that currently web essentials includes zencoding, so no need to install the second extension